Fixing hint placement in my Android application
So, I use TextInputLayout and EditText to input email, but I have some trouble with hint placement. I also don't know how to change the color of this "I" symbol. Here is my XML for this email field:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/test_email"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/logEmail"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:textColorHint="#616161"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


I forgot to add an image for this problem. Here is an example

Couple of mistakes here:

Wrong child view for com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.
Wrong style attribute value.
android:hint="@string/test_email" is used at wrong place.

Use code below:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="app"
        app:cursorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:hintEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/logEmail"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

In the code above:

Have corrected all the errors.
Used app:cursorColor to define caret (the "|" thing) color.


Oh my God, thank you so much! It really helped me. I wish you all the best and success!

Hi @arctg30, you can accept the answer as it solved your problem. Thanks.
